# Delay between filling up BatchBlock and it calling next ActionBlock

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am trying to understand how `BatchBlocks` and `ActionBlocks` work in .net `DataFlow`

I have an `ActionBlock` lets call it A1, which is fed from a loop, A1 would fetch some records from an API Asynchronously. Once the results are back, it posts the results back to a 'BatchBlock` (B1) with batch size as 5 which batches the results and posts it to another action (A2)

Now my expectation is as soon as A1 gets 5 results back, A2 should be called with result[4]. This does happen but not straight away, there is a substantial wait between A1 posting 5 items into B1 and then B1 calling A2.

not sure why there is so much wait.

`A1--`

```
var i = 0;
action = new ActionBlock<D1>(async d1 =>
           {
               var results = await QueryClientAsync(d1);
               if (results != null)
               {
                   await outgoingQueue.SendAsync(new Tuple<D1, IEnumerable<ScannedRecord>>(d1, GetRecordsFromQuery(d1.Name, results)));
                   Console.WriteLine($"Received {i++} {d1.Name} {DateTime.Now}");
               }
           }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxDegreeOfParallellismForQuery });
```

where `OutgoingQueue` is

```
outgoingQueue = new BatchBlock<Tuple<D1, IEnumerable<ScannedRecord>>>(BatchSizeForOutgoingCollection); // batch size = 5
```

and outgoingQueue is linked like this to `A2` --

```
var actionToProcessIncomingItems = new ActionBlock<Tuple<D1, IEnumerable<ScannedRecord>>[]>(
                ds =>
                {

                    Console.WriteLine($"Batch Recieved at {DateTime.Now}!");
                    ProcessCommonItems(ds);
                }
                , new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxDegreeOfParalleismToProcessRecievedItemsForScanner });

outgoingQueue.LinkTo(actionToProcessIncomingItems, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

Comment: Can you show how the delay is measured?

Comment: Sure editing question .. done!
So generally `i` is around 100 before batch received message is observed

Comment: I created a minimal repro of your code and it shows no significant delay between the last item in the batch processed and the batch passing to the final action block. I can post the results if you like but there's likely something else going on causing any delay.

Comment: On another note you should be using a `TransformBlock` for your first block, that would propagate the tuple automatically to the batch block without calling `SendAsync` on the `BatchBlock`

Comment: yea correct +1 for the tip, thanks for trying to repro it, not sure what else is coming in between these two. could be that am using all my cores to query api and get results for it to be free to call A2

Comment: @Muds: TPL Dataflow queues tasks to the thread pool to do its work - even if that work is just pushing data along. If your thread pool is saturated, there may be a significant delay due to the limited thread injection rate.

Comment: @StephenCleary that seems to be the case here, limiting Bounded capacity and max parallelism reduces the lag